# Sequence.js issues with hashTag

Tags: sequence, hashtag

I'm using sequence.js with Ben Alman's hashChange plugin.

It works fine, but for some reason it's making my navbuttons disappear.

I'm using jQuery v1.9.1, and also this plugin:
-Mouseover/ Click sound effect- by JavaScript Kit

Setup for Sequence.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var options = {
    autoPlay: false,
    nextButton: true,
    prevButton: true,
    preloader: true,
    cycle: false,
    navigationSkip: false,
    showPrevButtonOnInit: false,
    fallback:{
        theme: "slide",
        speed: 500
    },
    startingFrameID: 1,
    hashTags: false
};
var sequence = $("#sequence").sequence(options).data("sequence");});
```

I'm using this code to only show the previous and next buttons if there is a either previous or next slide:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var count = 1;

$('.sequence-next').click(function(){
    if(count == $('ul.sequence-canvas li').length - 1){

        $('.sequence-next').css('display','none');
    }
    $('img.sequence-prev').css('display','inline');
    if(count < $('ul.sequence-canvas li').length){
        count++;
    }
});
$('.sequence-prev').click(function(){
    $('.sequence-next').css('display','inline')
    if(count > 1){
        count--;
    }
    if(count == 1){
        $('img.sequence-prev').css('display','none');
    }

});   });
```

Comment: Please provide more information. It's tough for the community to help you if you aren't telling us about your system/installation/setups/...

Comment: Sorry.

I'll edit my original post to include more information.